# Specifying the helmet interface with Vorto

Tags: bosch-iot-suite, eclipse-vorto

how to simply do the smoke test with vorto?

use vorto to integrate ditto and devices

in the topo, device-hono-vorto-ditto, we want the simplist way to test the workflow, is there any method?

Comment: Hi Alan. What is a helmet interface? And what are you trying to achieve? Sorry, but I can't make sense of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the Vorto Semantic Middleware between Eclipse Hono and Eclipse Ditto, similar to https://github.com/eclipse/vorto-examples/tree/master/vorto-dashboard/docs/AssetTracking.md

The following tutorial, it is described how to set up the pipeline as well as to test it: https://github.com/eclipse/vorto/blob/development/docs/tutorials/create_mapping_pipeline.md
This tutorial does not mention Eclipse Ditto as a consumer of the pipeline, because it is important that the basic (Device-Hono-Vorto) pipeline works first before adding Eclipse Ditto in the equation.

Does your mapped / semantic data of the helmet appear in the middleware logs correctly ?